# Índice compuesto por dos campos

Tags: sql-server, django

Estoy aprendiendo de manera autodidacta Django con Base de datos SQL Server.

En mi ejercicio tengo dos tablas: *it_empresas* e *it_departamentos* con índices compuestos a través de SQL Server. Puedo tener distintos códigos de empresa pero con iguales codigos de departamentos, es decir:

- tabla it_empresa tengo cod=1 cod=2,
- tabla it_departamento cod_empresa llave foránea a it_empresa y cod_departamento Primary Key,

pero en el Administrador de Django no puedo agregar en la tabla it_departamentos 2 códigos de departamentos iguales aun cuando son cod de empresa diferentes.

Les dejo el modelo para una mejor explicación.

Modelo:

```
**class it_empresas(models.Model):
    cod = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=20 ,null=False, blank=False, 
          verbose_name='Codigo de Empresa')
    rut_legal = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=False, null=True)
    razon_social = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    direccion = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    comuna = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    fono = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    def nombre_empresa(self):
        return "{} - {}  - {}".format(self.cod, self.rut_legal, self.razon_social)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre_empresa()
    class Meta:
        #managed = False
        verbose_name = 'it_empresa'
        verbose_name_plural = 'it_empresas'
        db_table = 'it_empresas'
        ordering = ['cod']
    
class it_departamentos(models.Model):
    cod_empresa = models.ForeignKey(it_empresas, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, 
    db_column='cod_empresa', verbose_name='Codigo Empresa')
     cod_departamento = models.CharField(primary_key=True,max_length=20,blank=False, null=False, 
     verbose_name='Codigo de Departamento')
    nombre_departamento = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    def departamento(self):
       return "{} - {} - {}".format(self.cod_empresa, self.cod_departamento, self.nombre_departamento)
    def __str__(self):
       return self.departamento()
    class Meta:
        #managed = False
        verbose_name = 'it_departamento'
        verbose_name_plural = 'it_departamentos'
        db_table = 'it_departamentos'
        ordering = ['cod_empresa', 'cod_departamento']**
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/). Es decir le dices a Django que por cada empresa hay varios departamentos y viceversa.

En tu código tienes:

```
class it_departamentos(models.Model):
    cod_empresa = models.ForeignKey(it_empresas, on_delete = models.DO_NOTHING, 
    db_column='cod_empresa', verbose_name='Codigo Empresa')
```

`ForeignKey` es para indicar uno a muchos. Cambia `ForeignKey` por `ManyToManyField`

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, hice el cambio que sugieres, pero me sigue negando el agragar un codigo de departamento ya existente en otra empresa. El problema lo tengo al querer grabar un código que ya existe en otra empresa y no debería ser ya que es el código de departamento de otra empresa, sigo sin poder avanzar

Comment: Corriste las migraciones despues del cambio?

Comment: Gracias por responder Loki, olvide mencionar que estoy conectado a sql server, y si hice las migraciones, también abrí otra pregunta con el siguiente titulo "Django - Administrador El ORM no me deja hacer una relacion uno a mucho entre dos tabla", ahí talvez está más clara mi pregunta, te agradezco mucho si me puedes ayudar, saludos